# Creating random graphs using GraphStream Library

Tags: random, graph, graphstream

I have been coding a little with GraphStream library for a while now, and I want to create a random graph. Here is how I proceeded:

1. Create a graph
2. Create a random number generator, in my case, generates any number from 3 to 1000
3. Create a node and add it to the graph

My code is as follows:

```
public class Cluster1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //create a graph
    Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Cluster1");

    // generate a random number of nodes from 3-1000
    int numNodes = 3 + ((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 998));
    System.out.println("No of Nodes: " + numNodes + "\n");

    // add each to node to the graph
    for (int i = 1; i <= numNodes; i++) {
        Node (String.valueOf(i)) = graph.addNode(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    graph.display();
   }
}
```

It seems the error is from this line
`Node (String.valueOf(i)) = graph.addNode(String.valueOf(i));`
I used to create nodes and add them to a graph as follows:
`Node A = graph.addNode("A");`
I need to make the node variable name dynamic. This is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solve it:
`Node A[] = new Node[numNodes];
for (int i = 1; i<=numNodes-1; i++) {
    A[i] = graph.addNode(String.valueOf(i));
}`